# How to plot a stacked bar using the groupby data from the dataframe in python?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, matplotlib, visualization, stacked-chart

I am reading  huge csv file using pandas module.

`filename = pd.read_csv(filepath)`

Converted to Dataframe,

`df = pd.DataFrame(filename, index=None)`

From the csv file, I am concerned with the three columns of name country, year, and value.
I have groupby the country names and sum the values of it as in the following code and plot it as a bar graph.

`df.groupby('country').value.sum().plot(kind='bar')`

where, x axis is country and y axis is value.

Now, I want to make this bar graph as a stacked bar and used the third column year with different color bars representing each year. Looking forward for an easy way.
Note that, year column contains years from 2000 to 2019.
Thanks.

Comment: So, you want to change the order of axis in the plot??

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html

Comment: No. I have to implement the year data as a stackbar.

Comment: With different color bars representing each year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what i understand you should try something like :

`df.groupby(['country', 'Year']).value.sum().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)`